# Como puedo quitar objetos de un listado que están en otro listado?

Tags: c#, .net-core, linq-to-sql

Tengo un listado con una serie de objetos dynamicos y otros listado con otro resultado diferente y objeto dynamico como puedo decirle que me de los resultados del segundo listado que no esten en el primero ?

```
List<object> e1 = (from i in _tabladb1.GetDbSet()
                                                      join d in _tabladb2.GetDbSet() on i.IdE equals d.Id
                                                      where d.IdT == Tipo.V
                                                      && i.IdI != null
                                                      && d.FD == null && d.FB == null
                                                      && i.FD == null && i.FB == null
                                                      orderby d.RS ascending
                                                      select new
                                                      {
                                                          Id = d.Id,
                                                          Text = d.RS
                                                          N = d.N,
                                                          IdI = i.IdIR
                                                      }).Distinct().ToList<object>();

        List<object> e2 = (from i in _tabla1.GetDbSet()
                join d in _tabla2.GetDbSet() on i.IdE equals d.Id
                where d.IdT == Tipo.C
                && d.FD == null && d.FB == null
                && i.FD == null && i.FB == null
                orderby d.RS ascending
                select new
                {
                    Id = d.Id,
                    Text = d.RS,
                    Nif = d.N
                }).Distinct().ToList<object>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [Except](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0):

> Proporciona la diferencia de conjuntos de dos secuencias utilizando el
> comparador de igualdad predeterminado para comparar los valores.

En tu caso, lo siguiente debería devolver el resultado esperado:

```
var soloSegundaColeccion= e2.Except(e1);
```